# R some conditional probability distributions of node do not sum to one

Tags: r, bayesian

I'm building a Bayesian Network with the `bnlearn` packages in R. After building the tree I'm trying to query some probabilities and is returning the following error.... `Error in check.fit.dnode.spec(dist[[node]], node = node) : 
  some conditional probability distributions of node Sprinkler do not sum to one.`. When I go and check the `Sprinkler` it does add to one. Here is the outcome of `Sprinkler`...

```
             Rain
Slippery_Road true false
        true   0.7   0.3
        false  0.0   1.0
```

Here is my entire code...

```
require(bnlearn)

vname <- c('Winter', 'Sprinkler', 'Rain', 'Wet_Grass', 'Slippery_Road')
e <- empty.graph(vname)
arc.set <- matrix(c('Winter', 'Winter', 'Sprinkler', 'Rain', 'Rain', 
                'Sprinkler', 'Rain', 'Wet_Grass', 'Wet_Grass', 'Slippery_Road'),
              ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c('from', 'to')))
arcs(e) <- arc.set

# Winter
cptW <- matrix(c(0.6, 0.4), ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c('true', 'false')))
cptW

# Sprinkler
cptS <- c(0.2, 0.75, 0.8, 0.25)
dim(cptS) <- c(2, 2)
dimnames(cptS) <- list('Sprinkler' = c('true', 'false'),
                   'Winter' = c('true', 'false'))
cptS

# Rain
cptR <- c(0.8, 0.1, 0.2, 0.9)
dim(cptR) <- c(2, 2)
dimnames(cptR) <- list('Rain' = c('true', 'false'),
                   'Winter' = c('true', 'false'))
cptR

# Wet Grass
cptG <- c(0.95, 0.9, 0.05, 0.1, 0.8, 0, 0.02, 1)
dim(cptG) <- c(2, 2, 2)
dimnames(cptG) <- list('Wet_Grass' = c('true', 'false'),
                   'Rain' = c('true', 'false'),
                   'Sprinkler' = c('true', 'false'))
cptG

# Slippery Road
cptSR <- c(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1)
dim(cptSR) <- c(2, 2)
dimnames(cptSR) <- list('Slippery_Road' = c('true', 'false'),
                   'Rain' = c('true', 'false'))
cptSR

dfit <- custom.fit(e, dist = list(Winter = cptW, Sprinkler = cptS,
                              Rain = cptR, Wet_Grass = cptG,
                              Slippery_Road = cptSR))

# Calculating probabilities
cpquery(dfit, event = (Slippery_Road == 'false'), evidence = (Winter == 'true'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of points:

1. Wet Grass CPT is wrong (0.02 should be 0.2, a typo)?
2. Seems each CPT should be column stochastic, not row stochastic.

The following works:

```
require(bnlearn)

vname <- c('Winter', 'Sprinkler', 'Rain', 'Wet_Grass', 'Slippery_Road')
e <- empty.graph(vname)
arc.set <- matrix(c('Winter', 'Winter', 'Sprinkler', 'Rain', 'Rain', 
                    'Sprinkler', 'Rain', 'Wet_Grass', 'Wet_Grass', 'Slippery_Road'),
                  ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c('from', 'to')))
arcs(e) <- arc.set
```

The following is your Bayesian Network (DAG):

```
library(Rgraphviz)
plot(e)
```

[image]

```
# Winter
cptW <- matrix(c(0.6, 0.4), ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c('true', 'false')))
cptW

     true false
[1,]  0.6   0.4

# Sprinkler:  P(S|W) since the direction of the edge is W -> S
cptS <- c(0.2, 0.8, 0.75, 0.25)
dim(cptS) <- c(2, 2)
dimnames(cptS) <- list('Sprinkler' = c('true', 'false'),
                       'Winter' = c('true', 'false'))
cptS

          Winter
Sprinkler true false
    true   0.2  0.75
    false  0.8  0.25

# Rain: P(R|W)
cptR <- c(0.8, 0.2, 0.1, 0.9)
dim(cptR) <- c(2, 2)
dimnames(cptR) <- list('Rain' = c('true', 'false'),
                       'Winter' = c('true', 'false'))
cptR   

        Winter
Rain    true false
  true   0.8   0.1
  false  0.2   0.9

# Wet Grass P(WG|S,R)
cptG <- c(0.95, 0.05, 0.9, 0.1, 0.8, 0.2, 0, 1)
dim(cptG) <- c(2, 2, 2)
dimnames(cptG) <- list('Wet_Grass' = c('true', 'false'),
                       'Rain' = c('true', 'false'),
                       'Sprinkler' = c('true', 'false'))
cptG

, , Sprinkler = true

         Rain
Wet_Grass true false
    true  0.95   0.9
    false 0.05   0.1

, , Sprinkler = false

         Rain
Wet_Grass true false
    true   0.8     0
    false  0.2     1

# Slippery Road P(SR|R)
cptSR <- c(0.7, 0.3, 0, 1)
dim(cptSR) <- c(2, 2)
dimnames(cptSR) <- list('Slippery_Road' = c('true', 'false'),
                        'Rain' = c('true', 'false'))
cptSR

              Rain
Slippery_Road true false
        true   0.7     0
        false  0.3     1

dfit <- custom.fit(e, dist = list(Winter = cptW, Sprinkler = cptS,
                                  Rain = cptR, Wet_Grass = cptG,
                                  Slippery_Road = cptSR))

# Calculating probabilities
cpquery(dfit, event = (Slippery_Road == 'false'), evidence = (Winter == 'true'))
# [1] 0.4342105
```

Comment: The network drawn is directly from the adjacency matrix that you have defined, if it's not as per expectation then probably we need to double check the graph adjacency matrix (considering it to be a directed graph).